# Did The Narrator Ad-Dhahak Ever Met Ibn Abbas In His Lifetime?

Tags: hadith, tafseer, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal

I have read some controversial views about the meeting of Ad-Dhahak and Ibn Abbas. In one source, Ad-Dahak explicitly denies ever narrating anything from Ibn Abbas.

Some people cite Tafsir Ibn Kathir vol. 2 p. 71 and say that it is written in it that Ad-Dahak never met or narrated anything from Ibn Abbas.

According to a narration in al-Jarh wat-Ta'dil by Ibn Abi Hatim
ar-Razi, Ad-Dahak never met Ibn Abbas. In this book we can read,

> Ibn Abi Hatim narrates with an authentic isnad
> from 'Abd al-Malik ibn Abi Maysarah that he asked
> ad-Dahhak: **"Did you personally hear anything
> from Ibn 'Abbas?" Ad-Dahhak replied in the
> negative.** 'Abd al-Malik then asked him: "So this
> which you narrate (from him), from whom did
> you take it?" Ad-Dahhak replied: "From this one
> and that one."
>
> <sup>[Ibn Abi Hatim, al-Jarh wat-Ta'dil
> vol. 4 tarjamah no. 2024](https://al-maktaba.org/book/2170/2043)</sup>

However, Imam Ibn Hajr has written in his "Tahdheeb Al-Tahdheeb" that Ad-Dahak was a neighbour of Ibn Abbas.

> **"Abu Janab al-Kalabi narrated that al-Dahhak said: 'I neighboured Ibn Abbas for
> seven years."**
>
> <sup>[Imam Ibn Hajar Asqalani in Tahdeeb al-Tahdeeb, Volume 4 page 398](https://al-maktaba.org/book/3310/2032)</sup>

Ad-Dahak is found almost 34 times in Asbab-ul-Nuzul by Al Wahidi and he has narrated many narrations from Ibn Abbas.

Did Ad-Dahak never met Ibn Abbas?

Comment: Please note that ibn Abi Hatim ar-Razi is generally not referred to as ar-Razi to distinguish him from Fakhr ad-Dyn ar-Razi the known mufassir, physician and theologe and ar-Razi the physician. I guess this was the reason for my confusion in the other post. While he is generally known as ibn Abi Hatim who is both a mufassir and hadith scholar. I guess this was the reason for my confusion in the other post. Further a-Dahhak is well known and accepted as a great mufassir, but his hadith is not compiled in both Sahihs because there are simply better and more trustworthy narrators.

Comment: So far I can confirm the statement mentioned by ibn Abi Hatim. Imam a-Dhahabi says in his siyar a'lam an-Nubala that some people say he never met ibn 'Abbas.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - But Ibn Hajr Asqalani says that Dhahak met Ibn Abbas. What about that?